# RSpec + Javascript = BusyException: cannot rollback transaction

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem with this test :

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe "registration feature", :js => true do
  it "sign up user" do
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    visit login_path
    puts page.html
  end
end
```

It show the message : SQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction

I tried many think :

- when I remove ":js => true" it works.
- when I try with selenium or webkit it does not work.
- I tried to remove the DB or restart my PC and it doesn't work.
- I try with mysql and it works.

This is my spec_helper :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require "email_spec"
  require 'simplecov'  
  require "authlogic/test_case"
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :mocha
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
    config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
  end

  include Authlogic::TestCase

  require 'database_cleaner'
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.default_selector = :css
end

Spork.each_run do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  load "#{Rails.root}/config/routes.rb"
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
  I18n.backend.load_translations
end
```

And this is my test.rb :

```
Onopia::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
end
```

I realy don't know what to do. Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. I add this :

```
self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

after describe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better solution :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require "email_spec"
  require 'simplecov'  
  require "authlogic/test_case"
  require 'database_cleaner'

  SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :mocha
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.before(:suite, :type => :request) do
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each, :type => :request) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each, :type => :request) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.include(EmailSpec::Helpers)
    config.include(EmailSpec::Matchers)
  end

  include Authlogic::TestCase

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
  Capybara.default_selector = :css
end

Spork.each_run do
  load "#{Rails.root}/config/routes.rb"
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each { |f| load f }
  I18n.backend.load_translations
end
```